# HTML form radio button to submit or hide on click with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to use jquery to either submit or hide depending on the radio button that is clicked.  I am submitting the value to mysql.  The radio buttons are in a tr.  If I include a submit button in the form I can update mysql with the value successfully.

```
<tr>
    <form name="MyStatusForm" id="MyStatusForm" method="post" action="update.php">
        <td class="statuscolumn">
            <input name='status' type='radio' value='1' />
            <label for="new">New</label>
            <input name='status' type='radio' value='2' />
            <label for="accept">Accept</label>
            <input name='status' type='radio' value='3' />
            <label for="resolve">Resolve</label>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

My script looks for the value of the radio button to determine which action to take.

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
    var $closestTR = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $closestForm = $(this).closest('form');
    if (this.value == '1') || (this.value == '2') {
        $closestForm.submit();
    }
    if (this.value == '3') {
        var ok = confirm("some message?");
        if (ok == true) {
            $closestTR.hide("slow");
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

The hide works fine.  It is only the submit that doesn't work.  There is no response when I click the radio button and mysql is not updated.

Thanks for your help

Comment: That's invalid markup, the form should be inside the TD, not the other way around, and the TD should be closed properly.

Comment: Sorry, I have my TD closed, that was just a copy and paste error.  I corrected my example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your if, should be

```
if ((this.value == '1') || (this.value == '2'))
```

Also, don't forget to fix your markup as @adeneo suggested

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/s3r7X/)

Corrected Markup

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="statuscolumn">
            <form>
                <input name='status' type='radio' value='1' />
                <label for="new">New</label>
                <input name='status' type='radio' value='2' />
                <label for="accept">Accept</label>
                <input name='status' type='radio' value='3' />
                <label for="resolve">Resolve</label>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## **js**

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="status"]').click(function () {
    var $closestTR = $(this).parents('tr');
    $closestForm = $(this).parents('form');
    if (($(this).attr('value') == '1') || ($(this).attr('value') == '2')) {
        $closestForm.submit();
    }
    if (this.value == '3') {
        var ok = confirm("some message?");
        console.log(ok);
        if (ok == true) {
            $closestTR.hide();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```